# "PHP Warning: require(drupal.php): failed to open stream"

Tags: console

I have created two fresh installations of Drupal, one version 8.9.17 and the other 9.2.3 and have been trying to get the Drupal console to work so that I can generate a module.

I used the following command in Composer and successfully downloaded it.

```
composer require drupal/console:~1.0 \
--prefer-dist \
--optimize-autoloader \
--sort-packages \
--no-update
```

Then run the following to avoid a Symphony conflict error.

```
composer update
```

This downloaded the relevant files and dependencies but when I try to access it from the command line (see below)

```
$ ../../../../vendor/bin/drupal
```

I get the following error.

> Warning: require(drupal.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
> directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\project_name\vendor\bin\drupal(21) :
> eval()'d code on line 3     PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed
> opening required 'drupal.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\project_name\vendor\bin\drupal(21) : eval()'d code on line
> 3
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'drupal.php'
> (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\project_name\vendor\bin\drupal(21) : eval()'d
> code on line 3

I looked on the Drupal console website and the advice was

> This can be caused by the ioncube loader extension

As i'm working with Xammp on Windows 10, ioncube isn't available by default in the php.ini file. What should I be looking for to solve this?

**EDIT**
It has been pointed out to me that Drush now includes generating commands and should be used instead of Drupal console which appears to be obsolete.

Comment: Last I heard (a while ago now) Drupal Console was obsolete and unmaintained - all of the `generate` commands are available with Drush though

Comment: @Clive, Oh. I can't see that when I run Drush - https://pastebin.com/7BrZ4vXe but I have just looked on the Drush website and can see them listed there. Interesting, might need to do some more digging.

Comment: Yeah I use it all the time: https://imgur.com/a/WiDdY3w

Comment: @Clive, You are correct. Didn't realise it was listed under 'Global' - I'll need to check that out. Thanks!

Comment: @Clive one important and useful command missing in drush is entity type config export. Like node bundle config export. Which is present in Drupal console. Unless i am not aware of existing command.

Comment: I don't think so @miststudent2011, I think that command is missing/not implemented like you say. Features provides similar functionality I think

Comment: @clive Yes, features provides similar functionality but it wont export fields storage config which makes bundle config export useless. Unless I have made mistake while expoting configs via features.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so immediately after I posted the question I found the solution. I hope this helps anyone else in a similar situation.

The error is essentially saying that the drupal.php file cannot be found. So I went into the vendor/bin/drupal directory followed where the file was missing from:

```
vendor/drupal/console/bin/drupal
```

If you open that file, you will see the following code, which references the missing drupal.php file.

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
 
require 'drupal.php';
```

I compared this to Drush (which was working fine) and saw the Drush file was similar, but included the directory reference `__DIR__`. I updated the drupal.php file to the following and it now works as expected.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
    
require __DIR__ . '/drupal.php';
```